# How to get apache port from PHP CLI

Tags: php, apache, command-line-interface

We get the apache information when using `$_SERVER` from the **browser**.

I want to get that information from **CLI.**. How can i do that??

Comment: Can't you parse the apache configuration files for the host?

Comment: I am new to cli..Can you please tell how can i do that?

Comment: you can get little information by using [php_uname](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-uname.php). Check it out if it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

The SERVER_NAME is not available when you run PHP from the CLI for that very same reason.

When you run PHP from the CLI, you start your own PHP intepreter that runs whatever code you passed to it, without any kind of server. So from the CLI, PHP knows nothing about your web server that you do not explicitly tell it.

However, As of PHP 5.4.0, the CLI SAPI provides a built-in web server. Refer [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php).

Moreover, you can make a simple `test.php` as below:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

and fire it from cmd/terminal.

```
prompt>php test.php
```

Let me make it pristine that it will not give all the variables that are available when using via HTTP(browser), but will list whatever are available.

Comment: Well, frankly speaking. I dont know whether it can show a port of localhost (once its initialized) or not but yes you can specify the port that you want to use while initializing in-built webserver. Check -S option [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php). Note that its capital S.